# Retrieving the image name from a powerpoint file

Tags: c#, .net, openxml-sdk, presentation

I need to retrieve the image file name from an image in a pptx file. I already got the stream from the image but i didn't got the name of the image file... Here is my code:

```
private static Stream GetParagraphImage(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture     picture, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.PresentationDocument presentation, ref     MyProject.Import.Office.PowerPoint.Presentation.Paragraph paragraph)
{
        // Getting the image id
        var imageId = picture.BlipFill.Blip.Embed.Value;
        // Getting the stream of the image
        var part = apresentacao.PresentationPart.GetPartById(idImagem);
        var stream = part.GetStream();
        // Getting the image name
        var imageName = GetImageName(imageId, presentation);  
/* Here i need a method that returns the image file name based on the id of the image and the presentation object.*/
        // Setting my custom object ImageName property
        paragraph.ImageName = imageName;
        // Returning the stream
        return stream;
}
```

Anyone knows how i can accomplish this ?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There are in fact two file names for a picture/image in a pptx file:

If you need the file name of the image as it is embedded in the pptx file
you can use the following function:

```
public static string GetEmbeddedFileName(ImagePart part)
{
  return part.Uri.ToString();
}
```

If you need the orignial file system name of your image you can use the following function:

```
public static string GetOriginalFileSystemName(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture pic)
{
  return pic.NonVisualPictureProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Description;
}
```

**BEGIN EDIT:**

Here is a complete code example:

```
using (var doc = PresentationDocument.Open(fileName, false))
{
  var presentation = doc.PresentationPart.Presentation;

  foreach (SlideId slide_id in presentation.SlideIdList)
  {
    SlidePart slide_part = doc.PresentationPart.GetPartById(slide_id.RelationshipId) as SlidePart;
    if (slide_part == null || slide_part.Slide == null)
        continue;
    Slide slide = slide_part.Slide;

    foreach (var pic in slide.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture>())
    {
      string id = pic.NonVisualPictureProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Id;
      string desc = pic.NonVisualPictureProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Description;

      Console.Out.WriteLine(desc);
    }
  }
}
```

**END EDIT**

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Hii, thanks for the answer but the property NonVisualDrawingProperties doesn't exists directly in the Picture object... First i need retrieve the NonVisualPictureProperties then NonVisualDrawingProperties.Description, but when i acess this property, she returns null... There is some using or anything else that i need to type before?

Comment: @mnatan.brito: You're right. The NonVisualDrawingProperties property does not directly exist on the picture class. I've updates my answer with a more complete code sample. I've ran it again a power point 2007 document and it prints the original file names. Hope, this helps.

Comment: @mnatan.brito: Another option would be to rename your file.pptx into file.zip. Then open the zip archive and search for the orignial file name of one of your embedded images in all the files contained in the archive. If you do not find one then your pptx does not contain original file name information.